# Microsoft Custom Vision - Deleting a iteration doesn't delete images associated with it

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

On the Microsoft Custom Vision documentation there is this Note: "...When you delete an iteration, you end up deleting any images that are uniquely associated with it."

But when I use the Python `trainer.delete_iteration(project_id, iteration.id)` my images that are uniquely associated with the last trained iteration are not deleted.

Do I need to do something else or this is not working?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation may need to be updated. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/azure-cognitiveservices-vision-customvision/azure/cognitiveservices/vision/customvision/training/training_api.py#L1827) for the `delete_iteration` method it looks like it just sends the DELETE request to the iteration URL:

```
delete_iteration.metadata = {'url': '/projects/{projectId}/iterations/{iterationId}'}

url = self.delete_iteration.metadata['url']
path_format_arguments = {
  'projectId': self._serialize.url("project_id", project_id, 'str'),
  'iterationId': self._serialize.url("iteration_id", iteration_id, 'str')
}

url = self._client.format_url(url, **path_format_arguments)

request = self._client.delete(url, query_parameters)
response = self._client.send(request, header_parameters, stream=False, **operation_config)
```

So, in order to delete the associated images, it looks like you would need to use the `delete_images` method as well.

Comment: Yes, when I upload the images to the project I need to save the images_ids and if necessary delete them after using `delete_images`